# Publication from PhD thesis

Tags: thesis, paper-submission

my PhD thesis is very comprehensive and contains a lot of data.
My advisor says that we need to publish this thesis in 2 parts. (two interconnected articles, different findings but the same material).
In this case, would it be a problem to publish it as 2 different papers? There will be different findings in both but there is the same material as it is produced from the same thesis.
Would it be more advantageous to send both articles to the same journal or to different journals?

Comment: Have you asked your advisor these questions?

Comment: This is not so unusual. Authors usually like this option because it can improve h-index and similar metrics, considering also that you should cite the first article in the second one, having used the same data.

Comment: Totally normal - two papers came out of my thesis, published in different journals because they were rather different, and each was a better fit in a different place.

Answer (score 0):

What a journal will publish is up to them. So, whether is is a problem is up to the editor(s). There is an advantage to readers if the two articles are in the same journal, but also if you just publish a single long article. I doubt that it matters much for your reputation whether the two articles are in the same or different journals. Having two papers instead of one is good, but having a longer, highly significant, single paper is also good.

But, let me point out that you may be building in a problem for yourself with two papers. It is possible (likely?) that the novelty and impact of each of the two papers is lower than that of a single paper. If that is the case, then you lessen the likelihood of either getting published. But you know the material and you may be fine here.

I would proceed strategically, however. First outline the two articles and get a good sense that both would pass the threshold of publish-ability. Your advisor can give good advice here. Then, develop one of the papers completely (rather than both) and get it off to the most appropriate journal. While that paper is in progress with the journal, develop the second paper. Make a decision about whether and where to send it based on what you hear about the first paper.

This gets you into the process earlier than if you spend the time to complete both papers and also gives you feedback.

In the worst case that the first paper is rejected or requires a lot of revision, you can then submit the other to the same or another journal, or, potentially, make a further strategic decision about how to proceed.

This seems, to me, to be a better option than spending time to develop both to the same level and sending them both together. But that is only an opinion.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comments. The findings of both articles are different. However, in order to enrich the discussion sections, we made small quotes from each of the results of the two articles. And at the end of the second we wrote a common result. Now I doubt if there is an ethical problem in this situation. Also, is it a problem to publish in different journals since there are two different articles merged in the conclusion?

Comment: There aren't any ethical concerns as long as you cite your other work as necessary. There is a danger of self plagiarism that you avoid by cross citation. Your common result should probably be cross cited also, just to be clear.